# Can I assign permissions to a task list view?

Tags: permissions, list-view

My supervisor wants to be able to see all of his team's tasks in sharepoint (2010). He does not want them to be able to see each other's tasks.

I have tried making individual tasks lists for each person, but then in Outlook, in order to get a task re-assigned to someone from another's list, that person will have to connect Outlook to each team's list. That seems cumbersome. Also, my supervisor would then have to go to each person's list to see his/her tasks.

So the next thought was to leave everyone in one group and modify views. When the team members log in, they should only see "My Tasks" and be able to sort on those, removing "All Tasks" and other options that would allow them to see other's tasks. My supervisor would have the default view with all options to view/sort everyone.

Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking by assigning role/group permissions to these two views. But will those view permissions role through to Outlook as well.

I should add that we do not want to have to do any permissions at the item level.

Any thoughts or guidance on how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write a workflow (SharePoint Design er workflow is fine.)  Create a workflow that fires off when an item is created or modified.  Have the workflow change the permissions as follows:

1. Set permissions all the group that your boss is a member of (Say owners) have some sort of access.
2. Set the permissions to allow the assignee of the task to see the task.

That should do the trick

Comment: I do have a follow up question. I got this to work, as I stated before. But now I have the task list synched with my Outlook. If I create a task and assign it to someone else, it still shows up in MY Outlook. In Sharepoint, it only shows up for the assigned person's view (as it should).

How can I get the same permission/view to work in Outlook? Or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance for your insight and help!